# Password protecting template, secured content not showing if even password is right

Tags: password

Here is mine below code.
Now thing is that It perfectly asks the password for secured page.

But if even I add correct password. I still page asking for password.

Below is mine code.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Page
 *
 */
global $post; 
if ( ! post_password_required( $post ) ) {
get_header();

?>
<div id="Content">
    <div class="content_wrapper clearfix">
secured content here

</div>
</div>
<?php 

get_footer(); 
}else{
    // we will show password form here
    echo get_the_password_form();
}
```

Comment: Your current code looks strange, e.g. `?php` and `/div>`, please add your indented working code. Can you password protect normal pages, without this template?

Comment: updated,sorry I written here that section manually.

Comment: Try adding `while ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); }` at the top of the file - this will correctly set up the loop (even though it's just one post/page) and make sure all the code that follows functions correctly.

Comment: just adding it will work ? thing is that there is nothing going to come from the post. Still I should Add it ?

Comment: yup @TheDeadMedic it worked like charm. As I added that code after get_header(). But still it worked like charm. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved issue with suggestion of @TheDeadMedic.

Below is the code. As he told added while have post. I added it after header.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Page
 *
 */
global $post; 
if ( ! post_password_required( $post ) ) {
get_header();
while ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); }
?>
<div id="Content">
    <div class="content_wrapper clearfix">
secured content here

</div>
</div>
<?php 

get_footer(); 
}else{
    // we will show password form here
    echo get_the_password_form();
}
```